# is it passive or gerund? the request being sent to the server

Tags: grammar, meaning

happy new year .i wish you a year full of happiness i started reading a book about programming and i saw a sentence that couldn’t know it's structure:

> what React Router does is intercept the request being sent to the server

what i can’t understand is to use **being sent** after **noun**.
"being sent" is passive?

Comment: Ground? Do you mean _gerund_? Yes, _the request [which is] being sent_ is the passive voice.

Comment:  i mean gerund, thank you

Comment: The entire sequence *the request being sent to the server* is a ***noun phrase***, but that's not the case with the structurally similar constructions ***John being sent to Coventry,** no-one would speak to him,* and ***Mary being a Catholic**, she could not marry Joseph, who was a Protestant*.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think ***being*** in the cited context is "reduced" from ***which is being** [sent...]* or ***while it is being** [sent...]*. Most people would simply assume that same sense even if the actual word ***being*** was omitted (but *in theory*, if ***being*** wasn't included, it could mean that React Router intercepts requests *before* or *after* they're sent to the server, rather than ***while being sent***).

Comment: Just for the sake of academic interest, the "structurally similar constructions" @FumbleFingers mentioned are examples of the *nominative absolute* https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nominative%20absolute

Answer (score 1):

It is a rather complex sentence.

The content clause "What react does"  allows for a bare infinitive complement. So "intercept" is a bare infinitive. We could rephrase as

> React intercepts the request...

The verb "intercept" has an noun phrase for an object, the noun phrase is headed by the noun "request".  THat noun is modified by a participle phrase "being sent to the server".

The participle phrase is in the passive voice. The subject of the participle phrase is implied as "request", but as this is in the passive voice, that is the object of "send".  You could render in the active voice using a relative clause instead of a participle:

> the request (that is) being sent to the server  (passive)

> the request that {something} is sending to the server.

So "being sent" is a participle and in the passive voice.  It isn't a "gerund" (although the distinction between gerunds and present participles is not always clear or useful)

Comment: I'd say that "what React Router does" is a fused relative construction. The complement may be a _to_ infinitival or a bare one.